# Scala + Akka: pattern matching on type?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, akka

We have code like this scattered throughout our code base:

```
def receive: Receive = {
  case x: TypeX => doXishThingsWith(x)
  case y: TypeY => doYishThingsWith(y)
  case z: TypeZ => doZishThingsWith(z)
}
```

I find the need to give names to `x`, `y` and `z` kind of dumb and confusing.

I was wondering if something like this would work?

```
def receive: Receive = {
  case TypeX => doXishThingsWith(_)
  case TypeY => doYishThingsWith(_)
  case TypeZ => doZishThingsWith(_)
}
```

I have no idea if `_` actually works this way. But maybe there is something similar?

Comment: I wish Scala hadn't muddled up pattern matching with dispatch on type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. `case a: A => m(a)` is the shortest solution.

With `case TypeX` you are trying to match on companion object of `TypeX`, so you have to use underscore or variable name: `case _: TypeX`.

With `case _: TypeX` you have no access to variable.

#### Workaround

Actually you could use methods without variable names using some magic like this:

```
def receive: Receive = (
  pf[TypeX](doXishThingsWith) orElse
  pf[TypeY](doYishThingsWith) orElse
  pf[TypeZ](doZishThingsWith)
)
```

You have to create method `pf` like this:

```
import reflect.{ClassTag, classTag}

def pf[T: ClassTag](f: T => _): PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = {
  case e if classTag[T].runtimeClass.isInstance(e) => f(e.asInstanceOf[T])
}
```

Example:

```
class A; class B; class C

def mA(a: A) = println(s"mA!")
def mB(b: B) = println(s"mB!")

val receive = pf(mA) orElse pf(mB)

scala> receive.lift(new A)
mA!
res0: Option[Unit] = Some(())

scala> receive.lift(new B)
mB!
res1: Option[Unit] = Some(())

scala> receive.lift(new C)
res2: Option[Unit] = None
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do classical polymorphism:

```
trait T{
    def doThings()
}

class TypeX extends T{
    override def doThings() {
        println("doXishThingsWith")
    }
}

class TypeY extends T{
    override def do Things() {
        println("doYishThingsWith")
    }
}

def receive: Receive = {
  case x: T => x.doThings()
}
```

using underscore in pattern matching just means throw that value away and do not make it accessible from any variable

Comment: In general messages for actors are case classes without additional domain logic.

Comment: Thanks for the advice about underscore; I was trying to port over my knowledge from using it in functions (e.g. `.map(_ + 2)`)